# Dashboard like module that works with Panels

Tags: panels, dashboard

Dashboard module lets users change the dashboard according to their preferences. IS there a similar module which does the same for panels.

For example.

1. An admin user decides which blocks should be available on a particular page.
2. Each user can decide the order in which these blocks should be shown for him and whether they should be shown at all.

Answer (score 1):

[Dashboardify](http://Dashboardify)

> Dashboardify is a module for creating complex dashboards.
>
> Each user with proper permissions can add any block to dashboard and
>   rearrange blocks order on his or her dashboard page. There is one
>   dashboard with predefined regions available for each user. User can
>   add unlimited instances of the same block which can be useful for
>   views blocks with different contextual filters applied. Along with
>   block information module stores data what contextual filters were used
>   while adding block to dashboard. Block order is autosave via AJAX.

[Panel Dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_dashboard)

> Allows users to locally rearrange and roll up panes on the panel and
>   save the state per account. Global state of the panel is not modified
>   in the process.

[Total Control Admin Dashboard](https://www.drupal.org/project/total_control)

> The Total Control Admin Dashboard creates a default panel page with
>   useful administration tools. Its purpose is to create a central
>   location from which a Drupal site can be properly cared for. Several
>   overview panes are included for site stats and quick reference.
>   Several administration panes are provided with quick links to content
>   types, menus, taxonomy, and other scattered locations of important
>   Drupal site administration. Several views panes are also provided as
>   well as full-page comprehensive versions of the views with bulk
>   operations. Each views panel pane is customizable via it's pane
>   settings, or override the default views provided to suit your own
>   needs.